# Compiling mDNSResponder for Linux?

Tags: linux, compilation, bonjour

I've been trying to compile the open source Bonjour framework developed by Apple for Linux. The problem I have is that when I run make with the option `os=linux` I get the following compile error:

> struct sockaddr has no member named 'sa_len'

I've checked the struct sockddr and it indeed has no member named sa_len... So I'm confused as to why the framework is thinking that it should do!

Could anyone please give me some advice as to how I should be compiling mDNSResponder for Linux? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in mDNSUNP.h one can see that if `sa_len` does not exist (such as on Linux), a macro `NOT_HAVE_SA_LEN` should be defined. If it's not defined in your case, try adding `-DNOT_HAVE_SA_LEN` to your compilation flags.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux implementation of sockaddr doesn't have sa_len as a member, but the FreeBSD version does.  Apple's implementation is based off of the FreeBSD version ([parts of OS X pull from FreeBSD and NetBSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X#History)), hence why you're receiving that error.  You can use an `#ifdef` to workaround it or add the compilation flag, as previously suggested.